# Codeigniter PHPASS Logging In

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpass

I am using phpass for my login in codeigniter. But can not log on, there are know errors showing up I am not sure what the go is. Username and password correct. I have the library user in my system folder because I use multiple ci installs. I am just unsure why not letting me login. Even though username and password correct

Currently know errors are showing.

Library File

```
public function __construct() {

$this->CI =& get_instance();
$this->CI->load->database();
// Libraries
$this->CI->load->library('session');
$this->CI->load->library('security/rwdsecurity');
// Models
$file = dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/modules/backend/models/user/user_model.php';
$file = dirname(FCPATH) . '/install/application/modules/setup/models/install_model.php';

if(file_exists($file)) {
return true;
} else {
echo "Can't find file located in: " . $file;
}
}

public function login($username, $password) {
$username = $this->CI->db->where('username', $this->CI->input->post('username'));
$password = $this->CI->db->where('password', $this->CI->input->post('password'));
$user_query = $this->CI->db->get('user');

if($user_query->num_rows() ==  1) {
$data = array(
'username' => $this->CI->input->post('username'),
'isLogged' => true
);

$this->CI->sessions->set_userdata('user', $data);
$this->CI->rwdsecurity->check_password($password, $stored_hash);
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('isLogged') == false) {
$this->login();
} else {
redirect('dashboard');
}
}

function login_credentials() {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[12]|xss_clean|callback_validate');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');

if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == false) {
$data['action'] = site_url('login/login_credentials');
$this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);

} else {
$is_valid = $this->user->login($username, $password);

if($is_valid) {

$data = array(
  'username' => $username,
  'isLogged' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
}

 redirect('dashboard');
}
}

function validate($username, $password) {
if($this->user->login($username, $password)) {
return true;
} else {
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate', "Incorrect Username Or Password");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing?

Comment: As I said no errors. Just not login me on even though password and username correct

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're setting a session anywhere?

Comment: And also a note: You're setting `$file` twice, meaning you overwrite the first instance, possibly causing issues..

Comment: that locate my models though

Comment: I just tried it with one same issue not letting me login that's not the cause of it.

Comment: Do you set the sessions though?

Comment: I don't have any sessions set yet. I thought would be able to login with out theme first.

Comment: You need a session to login otherwise you'll just get redirected back to your login?

Comment: I added sessions edited toptic

Comment: Nothing as you can see in the new edited version I have put in my index. $this->session->userdata('isLogged') == false